# Html embed tag autostart="false" not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I use html tag "embed" for display audio, video and images in my page, but when I load the page the video and audio begin to play without clicking on "Play" button.  Setting `autostart="false"` and `autostart="0"` does not help.  How can I fix my problem?  Would some js/jquery code fix my problem? Maybe do you know some working analogs tag "embed" ? This is code:

```
<embed src="http://localhost:8080/upload/video.mp4" width="300" height="250" autostart="0"> </embed>
```

Comment: Post your code as we can't assume the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 tag `video`:

```
<video width="300" height="250" controls>
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/upload/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Not working:**

Change it to:

```
autostart="0"
```

Comment: @mvoron what about autostart=0 (without the quotes)